# How to add ripple animation to widget with custom background?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, ripple

How to implement following hover (Ripple) in android?
I have a linear layout and i want when user touched the layout all widgets in linear layout become lighter.
[image: hover]

Comment: @ZeusAlmighty You should not ask for nor pressure the Question author to accept nor vote on your Answer.

Answer (score 1):

Create a ripple drawable in res/drawable:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:color="@color/ripple"
    tools:targetApi="lollipop">
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/ripple" />
            <corners android:radius="@dimen/dp_6" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

Set this drawable to the button foreground:

```xml
android:foreground = "@drawable/bg_btn_ripple_animation"
```

You can modify the ripple drawable as per your liking.

Comment: Will work only if `onClick` in XML or `setOnClickListener ` methode is setted.

Comment: Which will be the case for all three buttons right?

Comment: It will be ripple animation for whole layout from touch position to edges.

Comment: Set it to `Button`'s background then it will limit to bounds of `Button`

Comment: Not what i really wanted!

Comment: @Mohrez khorasani Can you explain a bit how does it differ from the expected behaviour so I can help?

Comment: @ZeusAlmighty Please look at [this](https://streamable.com/h66351) video